# How do I return the correct type for nested includes in Prisma?

Tags: typescript, nested, prisma, return-type

I am unable to return the correct type from a function when using a query with nested includes. The nested fields are missing. I use a model similar to this one:

```
model Foo {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  bar Bar[]
}

model Bar {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  foo Foo @relation(fields: [fooId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  fooId String
  baz Baz[]
}

model Baz {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  bar Bar @relation(fields: [barId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  barId String
}
```

The type of `foo` contains `['bar'][number]['baz']` in this case:

```js
async function getFooById(id: Foo['id']) {
  return prisma.foo.findUnique({
    where: { id },
    include: { bar: { include: { baz: true } } },
  })
}

const foo = await getFooById('123')

if (foo !== null) {
  const baz = foo.bar[0].baz
}
```

If I try to parametrize the include, which I am probably typing incorrectly, it stops working:

```js
import type { DefaultArgs } from '@prisma/client/runtime/library.js'

async function getFooById(
  id: Foo['id'],
  // this line is probably the cause for the error?
  { include }: { include: Prisma.FooInclude<DefaultArgs> } = { include: {} },
) {
  return prisma.foo.findUnique({
    where: { id },
    include,
  })
}

const foo = await getFooById('123', include: { bar: { include: { baz: true } } })

if (foo !== null) {
  // error: baz is not defined on foo.bar[0]
  const baz = foo.bar[0].baz
}
```

**I feel that I need to specify a different argument type or possibly explicitly derive the return type based on the argument - but how?**

Another variant, which did also not work include `baz` in the resulting return type:

```js
async function getFooById<ExtArgs extends Types.Extensions.InternalArgs = Types.Extensions.DefaultArgs>(
  id: Foo['id'],
  { include }: { include: Prisma.FooInclude<ExtArgs> } = { include: {} },
) {
  // …
}
```

The version of Prisma used is 5.8.0, Typescript is 5.3.3.